# Modification of the table

Tags: javascript, webdatarocks

Good afternoon, is it possible to modify the table so as to add columns after the total? Excel demonstrates the option that we are striving for.

[webdatarocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWwnW.png)

[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBlwU.png)

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. Before you ask please check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can help you easily.

Answer (score 0):

WebDataRocks is a tool for a visual representation of the existing data, therefore, it does not provide the possibility to add additional columns.